# Hackerrank Algorithms Challenge Problem - showing type error in hackerrank environment (node) but works fine on the browser console. Whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(n, ar) {
let max = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if(ar[i] > max) {
        max = ar[i];
    }
}
let count = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    if(ar[i] === max) {
        count++;
    }
}
return count;
}
```

This runs perfectly on the browser console but when I run it in the Hackerrank environment (node) it throws this error:

Runtime Error:

> Error (stderr)
>   solution.js:30
>       for (let i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>       at birthdayCakeCandles (solution.js:30:28)

Any explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function accepts only *one* parameter, not two. Look at how it's invoked:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/birthday-cake-candles/problem

```
let result = birthdayCakeCandles(ar);
```

So, if you define `birthdayCakeCandles` to accept a second parameter (or any other parameters beyond the first), they will always be `undefined`.

Not sure what your `n` parameter is intended to be, but you should just remove it:

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(ar) {
```

and your code passes all the test cases.

Read the "function description":

> Function Description
>
> Complete the function birthdayCakeCandles in the editor below. It must return an integer representing the number of candles she can blow out.
>
> birthdayCakeCandles has the following parameter(s):
>
> ar: an array of integers representing candle heights

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I did not read the problem statement properly, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting only one parameter not two.

```
function birthdayCakeCandles(ar) {


}  // function from hackerRank question
```

So you need to remove the `n`. As you have `ar` as your second parameter so it turn out to be undefined cause in function call only one parameter is passed in your case which will map to `n`